# Making bootstrap form not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following dare I say good looking login form, but when I resize the browser, it compresses. This is due to the `<div class='col-xs-3'>`code. Is there any way within Bootstrap to keep the same look, without having to write CSS?

```
    <form name='login' action=' ' method='post'>
    <p>
    <form class='form-horizontal'>
    <fieldset>


    <!-- Text input-->
       <div class='col-xs-3'>
  <div class='control-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='textinput'>Username </label>
  <div class='controls'>
  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='username' />
  </div>
 </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='Password'>Password</label>
    <div class='controls'>
    <input type='password' class='form-control' name='password' />
   </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Text input-->

  <!-- Button -->
  <div class='control-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for=''></label>
  <div class='controls'>
  </div>
  <button type='submit' value='Login' class='btn btn-default'>Log In</button>
   </div>
    <br>
   <a href='forgot-password.php'>Forgot Password?</a>

 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
  <div id='bottom'></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the responsive behaviour is not so easy like turn the switch off. You'll need to edit a minimal CSS code.

From the **[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)**

**Steps to disable page responsiveness**

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the [**CSS docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile).
2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a
   single width, for example `width: 970px !important`; Be sure that this
   comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the
   `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try these:

1. Delete this : `<form name='login' action=' ' method='post'>`
2. Change this : `<form class='form-horizontal'>` into `<form class='form-horizontal' style="width:920px !important">`

Untested but should work. Let me know if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the div in question with the following code does the job:

```
.col-custom {
 position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-custom {
 float: left;
}
```